# Porting php code that extracts public key from certificate and encrypt data to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I wrote these two methods in PHP.
The first method, get_pubkey, extracts the public key from a certificate (certnew.cer) and the second method, encryptit(info) returns the encrypted information using the public key extracted by the first function.
I need to port these 2 functions to their Javascript equivalent. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
class Assdig 
{

   private $pubkey;

   /* (... )*/

   public function get_pubkey()
   {
       $certificado = __DIR__ . '/certnew.cer';

       $fp=fopen($certificado,"r"); 

       $this->pubkey=fread($fp,8192);

       fclose($fp);

       openssl_get_publickey($this->pubkey);
   }

   public function encryptit($info)
   {
     openssl_public_encrypt($info, $infoencrypted, $this->pubkey);

     return base64_encode($infoencrypted);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you mean javascript code which runs on a local machine or server ? (as opposed to in a webbrowser).

The PHP functions in question are just wrappers around the `openssl` library. I imagine the easiest method would be to just execute the `openssl` binary from your js code.

`man openssl-pkey` lists most of the relevant commands